# Need RegEx for following scenario in Perl

Tags: php, regex, perl

Hi Friends Im new to perl, I need a Regex to find like what i highlighted below, can some one give solution ?

**& # x 2003;Ferrara-Florence** 33, 58

**Saint Patrick & # x 2019; s Purgatory** 1, 2, 5, 6, 11–12, 16, 20, 27, 61, 86, 105–6, 127–62, 179, 184–5, 219, 233, 237–8, 260

**Checco Rossi da Meleto** 70, 127, 140–3, 151

**Aragona, Tullia d& # x 2019;** 127, 161–2

**Checco** 70, 127, 140–3

**& # x2003;Ferrara-Florence** 33, 58

**M & # x00FC;ns & # x 00FC;ter, Sebas & # x00FC;tia & # x00FC;n** 215, 228–32

**Machiavelli, Niccolò** 7–8, 15, 26, 37– 8, 67, 74, 159, 245, 249–50

I gave extra space to show the decimal characters

Thank you

Comment: As a tip, it seems to be easier to match the part you don't want, since it is just `[\d,\s-]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this one :**

```
(.+?)(?:[\d\-]+,\s)+.+
```

**Demo :**

http://rubular.com/r/VAsBRQaRmV

and another demo (with explanation and a minor edit) : http://regex101.com/r/mS9oN3

Comment: thanks you so much Dr.Kameleon,  It works! but i forgot to add 1 more item (eg : funerals 188&#x2013;9, 198, 230) this case it matches as (funerals 188&#x2013) but i need is (funerals)

Comment: @user3354853 OK, give me a second

Comment: what i need is all the contents before the number and comma starts (eg : Saint Patrick & # x 2019; s Purgatory 1, 2, 5, 6, 11–12, 16, 20, 27, 61, 86, 105–6, 127–62, 179, 184–5, 219, 233, 237–8, 260) need as (Saint Patrick & # x 2019; s Purgatory)

Comment: Well, I'm a bit confused. For `Aragona, Tullia d& # x 2019; 127, 161–2`, you want `Aragona, Tullia d& # x 2019;` while for `funerals...` you just need `funerals`?

Comment: Thank you so much Dr.Kameleon for your kind help, and sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

you can try this pattern:

```
(?m)^(?>& *# *x *[A-F0-9]{4};|[\p{L} ,-]+?(?= |&))+
```

Comment: Thank you! but this pattern includes ",<space>" also  eg: Checco Rossi da Meleto 70[, ]127[, ]140&#x2013; 3[, ]151

Comment: Thank You so much Casimir et Hippolyte it works perfectly Sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^(.+?)\s+(?=\d+[,-])
```

Comment: Thank you M42 for you help, sorry for late reply